# Installing .msi remotely without powershell?

Tags: batch-file, deployment, vbscript, installation, windows-installer

We have a **multi server system** that we need to install at a client site. I would like to put together a script that can:

1. Turn off services on remote machines
2. Uninstall software on several remote machines
3. Install .msi files several remote machines

I've struggled with **psexec** and **wmic** to do points #2 and #3.

It seems like there has to be an easier way without having to resort to **PowerShell**.

Comment: I suppose most sites have a deployment software such as [SCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager) (formerly SMS), [IBM's Tivoli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivoli_Management_Framework), [CA Unicenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Unicenter) or similar. Perhaps this is even available there?

Comment: If these deployment tools are available, I would not recommend messing with scripts of any kind. If not, please see my other answer below.

Answer (score 1):

First, see this thread for **WSH Remoting**: [**Remote Install on Windows Server 2012 R2**](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=21704).

Then, you can perhaps you can try to use a **VBScript library** such as that available in [**VbsEdit**](http://www.vbsedit.com/) (I don't like to make software recommendations, but I assume it is allowed since I am not affiliated and want to suggest it to solve the problem):

**Here is a script to install software remotely:**

```
' Install Software on a Remote Computer
Const wbemImpersonationLevelDelegate = 4

Set objWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objConnection = objwbemLocator.ConnectServer _
    ("WebServer", "root\cimv2", "fabrikam\administrator", _
         "password", , "kerberos:WebServer")
objConnection.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = wbemImpersonationLevelDelegate

Set objSoftware = objConnection.Get("Win32_Product")
errReturn = objSoftware.Install("\\atl-dc-02\scripts\1561_lab.msi",,True)
```

**Here is a script to stop services:**

```vb
' Stop Services Running Under a Specific Account
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Service Where StartName = '.\netsvc'")

For Each objService in colServices 
    errReturnCode = objService.StopService()
Next
```

---

**Here is a screen shot from VbsEdit's script library:**

[image: VbsEdit Search Samples]