# Deploy MSI files as an admin for normal user

Tags: windows-installer

I am maybe sorry for stupid question, but I've been googling it for a long time and found no solution, nothing works for me.
The thing is - I'd need regulary deploy a new version of our internal apps. Currently we're all at homeoffice and connected through VPN, so I'd love to write some BAT file to deploy the newest MSI. It doesn't have to be automatical, the users can start the update by themselves (= they can run the BAT when needed).
I am struggling with admin credentials - is there any way, how the normal users can just run a bat and somehow the admin credentials will be used for installation? I tried PsExec, but this is blocked on our firewalls, so PsExec can't connect to the computer.

My idea is that MSI file will be on our sharedrive and BAT can be stored locally. The user will run the BAT file, which will copy the MSI to local drive and run it as admin.
All works except the admin thing.

Would anyone, please, have any idea, how to sort it out? I'd say that /savecred is the last option for me. I am not really experienced in this, so once again, sorry for asking. But currently I need to remotely join to each person and do the installations manually and this would save me lot, I mean lot, of time..
Thank you so much in advance, if anyone knows or have any advice..

Comment: Voting to move this question to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

***Auto Update?***: [Various Auto-Update technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591399/what-is-the-best-practice-to-auto-upgrade-msi-based-application/51601083#51601083) (check [AppV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_App-V) and [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview) - per-user installs / non-admin deployment by design - [lots of limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/know-your-installer) - [MSIX Tutorial: A comprehensive 24-chapter guide](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html)).

---

***AlwaysInstallElevated***: There is the old AlwaysInstallElevated setting that shouldn't really be used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/alwaysinstallelevated - it is primarily a debugging construct (and a massive security hole). You can set it via the registry manually or use GPO. I think it is in Admin Templates/Windows Components/Windows Installer. [See here](https://serverfault.com/questions/19341/how-do-i-run-a-msi-installer-with-elevated-priviledges-on-windows).

***Scheduled Task***: Could you use scheduled task to install elevated in silent mode? I have never actually done this, but it should be possible. You can automate scheduled tasks easily in this day and age.

***GPO***: Is this an Active Directory environment where you can publish MSI files via GPO?

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-gpo.html
- [Use Group Policy to remotely install software](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/use-group-policy-to-install-software)

There are also the [**`psexec.exe`**](https://serverfault.com/a/25755/20599), [**`runas`**](https://serverfault.com/a/19343/20599) and other approaches using [**`VBScript`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880264/installing-msi-remotely-without-powershell/26885487#26885487). See below. I guess the question is if the users need to invoke the install themselves or you can kick it off?

---

***Links:***

- [Installing msi via a batch file to a remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644756/installing-msi-via-a-batch-file-to-a-remote-computer/60646270#60646270)
- [Installing .msi remotely without powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880264/installing-msi-remotely-without-powershell/26885487#26885487)
- [Issue installing MSI silently using msiexec, possible syntax issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463602/issue-installing-msi-silently-using-msiexec-possible-syntax-issue/55476766#55476766)
- [Runas service](https://serverfault.com/a/104377/20599)